# Accurately Computing a Positive Vector in the Nullspace of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerics, linear-system, condition-number, nullspace

I'm sure this question has been asked before yet after many hours of searching I am unable to find a definitive answer.

The problem at hand is solving the linear system: $$A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$$ with the constraint: $$ x_i \geq  0 $$
At present I apply SVD to obtain a set of vectors which span the nullspace of the matrix. The threshold used for zero singular values is  max(1e-12, 1e-15 x $\sigma_0$), where $\sigma_0$ is the greatest singular value. From these I search for a basis vector with the components all of the same sign. This is clearly suboptimal as any solutions which are linear combinations of the nullspace vectors are will be missed but I am unsure how to solve the resulting system of inequalities (possibly linear programming).

However a much more significant is issue dealing with rounding errors. The SVD method worked well for small matrices but as they increase in size (currently 64x64) it seems to result in vectors which are not in the nullspace, or with huge rounding errors when I come to verify they are solutions.  Below I have plotted the maximum absolute value of the result of plugging a candidate solution back into the equation against the condition number and rank of the matrix. This issue becomes worse for lower ranks of A.

[image: ![Maximum relative value of Ax vs rank of A]
[image]

The value of $\mathbf{x}$ is used to compute a function of the matrix and solution which can also be obtained via a prohibitively expensive alternative to finding positive nullspace vector. This is possible because x is normalised to a probability vector which can be obtained via Monte Carlo simulation. These probabilities are then used to calculate a single value which is a function of $\mathbf{x}$ and $A$. Points in green are in agreement with the Monte Carlo simulation and red are not.

I am sure there must be some way of solving this problem for matrices of this size. In general my matrix is ~90% zeros so sparse matrix methods may be suitable, particularly as the sparsity will increase as I increase the size of the matrices.

I would like some advice on how to proceed with the problems presented here, primarily the issue of accurately computing nullspace vectors and secondarily, solving a linear system of inequalities and if sparse methods may be helpful.

Comment: (1) If your matrices are singular by design, that "condition number" is meaningless; it will be just rounding errors. (2) Similarly, $\|Ax\|_\infty$ is useless because it is absolute (unscaled); plot $\|Ax\|_\infty / \|A\|_\infty\|x\|_\infty$ instead. (3) What do red and green points mean exactly? I can't understand the description. (4) What are you using as a threshold to distinguish zero and nonzero singular values?

Comment: Anyway, that looks like a difficult problem; I think linear programming is going to be the best alternative in general, unless your problem has something special ($A$ isn't an M-matrix perchance?). But first you need to have a reliable way to determine the rank of $A$.

Comment: Just to clarify, $max(|(Ax)_i|)$ is the maximal component of $Ax$. I am unsure if this is what you mean by $||Ax||_\inf$ but if so I will update the plots as you suggest. I have plots with the ratio of the maximum and minimal values of A instead of the singular value which I will include. Despite these being singular matrices, the determinant comes out as $\pm \inf$ using np.linalg.det,

Comment: Yes, $\|y\|_{\infty}$ is a common notation for the [maximum norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Maximum_norm_(special_case_of:_infinity_norm,_uniform_norm,_or_supremum_norm)) of a vector. Do not trust `det`; is useless for numerical computations; on moderately large matrices it will overflow.

Comment: Okay, thanks. As a threshold for the singular values I am using max(1e-12, 1e-15 x $\sigma_0$) where $\sigma_0$ is the largest singular value.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Does that threshold make sense for your problems? is there a visible gap in the singular values if you plot them? Is there a known exact value of the rank that you can compare to? Deciding what is zero and what is not is often a tricky thing to do numerically, and it sounds like it could be your main problem here.

Comment: Yes, determining what is zero and what is just relatively small is the major difficulty here, if I decrease the tolerances I end up with no solutions. How can I figure out what is an appropriate threshold for the problem? I will attempt to plot the singular values for individual matrices see if that helps. I have updated the question to include relative plots and tried to explain what the green and red points are. Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: I have had a brief look at the definition of an M-matrix and my $A$ cannot be one as the off diagonal elements are non-negative by construction.

Comment: Thanks for the info (and for editing it in). I see that your relative residuals $\|Ax\|_\infty / \|A\|_\infty \|x\|_\infty$ are as small as the machine precision; this seems to indicate that your vectors *are* numerically in the kernel of $A$. I don't think you can expect much better from a numerical algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think the cause of the discrepancy with the monte carlo (green vs red) is not a numerical issue at all. P.S. A quick examination of the eigenvalues of the matrices used to generate the data in the plots shows they are all negative, so $A$ may indeed be the negative of an M-matrix.

Comment: This problem will probably have multiple solutions. Maybe that is what caused the discrepancy?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking, it explains why there are so few red points at high rank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer to summarize my comments.

- Keep in mind that a delicate point is the choice of the truncation threshold in the SVD (what is "numerically zero" and what is not). If you do not see a clear drop in the singular values, then it means your precision is insufficient to identify zeros.
- Since $\|Ax\|_\infty / \|A\|_\infty \|x\|_\infty$ is of the order of machine precision, your plots show that the vectors you computed are (numerically) in the kernel of $A$, so the numerical method seems to be working correctly.
- A possible source for the discrepancy that you observe is that this problem has multiple solutions. Are you sure that you are computing the correct one?
- If $A$ (or $-A$) is an M-matrix, then there might be better solutions to your problem: irreducible M-matrices have a kernel of dimension $1$ spanned by a positive vector; so you just need to reduce your matrix to irreducible components (i.e., block-triangularize it) and compute the vector in the kernel of each of the singular diagonal blocks (which is unique up to scaling).

Comment: Thanks for the summary. I have attempted a linear programming approach which improves the accuracy but fails for a significant number of cases and does not perform well. For this reason I have begun to investigate M-matrices as you have suggested and I think I may be able to prove my A is an M-matrix using the characterisation detailed in "R. Plemmons, Nonnegative Matrices in the Mathematical Science" p149, however I need time to check this and familiarise myself with some issues with the notation.

Comment: Numerical investigations thus far have supported the assumption that they are indeed M-matrices but I am not sure how to implement the block-triangularisation (I assume this means to split the matrix into blocks and perform row operations on the entire matrix until each block is zero above or below it's diagonal) and then extract the nullspace vector. Will I find a library function to do this eg scipy or will I need to write my own?

Comment: I am glad to hear that the M-matrix tip helped! No, that is a different kind of reduction: you reorder column and row indices symmetrically so that your matrix becomes block triangular with irreducible blocks. Essentially, you wish to split the directed graph associated with the matrix into strongly connected components. This is purely a symbolic operation, without actual floating-point computations in it.

Comment: There is probably something inside the scipy graph libraries, but I am not sure exactly where to look. Also, it is possible that this comes from free from the structure of your problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right! If I interpret the matrix as a directed graph (ignoring the diagonal elements) there is a path between any two given nodes, thus the entire graph is strongly connected. But I don't see how this helps with the nullspace calculation.

Comment: Irreducible M-matrices have a kernel of dimension 1, spanned by a vector with positive entries: this is a consequence of the Perron--Frobenius theorem, and should be treated in Berman--Plemmons (it's a while since I used that book though, so I don't have an exact reference). So you should have only one zero singular value, in exact arithmetic, and the other ones are spurious. That is the first interesting bit of information.

Comment: Numerically, there are dedicated algorithms to compute this vector with very high precision; see e.g. https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2002-71-237/S0025-5718-01-01325-4/S0025-5718-01-01325-4.pdf . In your case, the algorithms in their Section 3 (GTH-like algorithm) should do the job, since essentially you just have to compute an accurate LU decomposition to find the nullspace.

Comment: Following your advice I have implemented something similar to the GTH algorithm to solve my problem nicely. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! I am glad to be of help, @cyfirx .